# Migrating Magento 1 customer Reward points to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration, data-migration-tool, reward-points

I'm currently trying to Migrate My data from Magento 1 to Magento 2 and running into some issues with migrating reward points.

We have J2T installed on our current Magento 1.9 site which has been OK but unfortunately does not seem to be compatible with our Magento 2.2.7.

We have decided to transfer over to Mirasvit. We have Ubertheme which Migrates customers, products and sale data fine but does not migrate reward points.

As we have a large number of customers (over 18,000) it would obviously not be feasible to go through the records and add the rewards points manually so I'm hoping that someone has come across this issue before and can suggest a solution/workaround.

Mirasvit's website the following but I'm unsure of how to make it work with the J2T on Magento 1

https://mirasvit.com/docs/module-rewards/current/setup/migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. After some back and forth with Mirasvit, the solution they have provided is as follows:

Obtain the following PHP file from Mirasvit (you have to contact them directly):

- mirasvit_migrate_j2t_rwp.php

You need to download a copy of Mirasvit Reward points for Magento 1 (you will also need to contact mirasvit about this).

1. Disable J2T extension in your M1 store (but don't remove it)
2. Install and enable Mirasvit extension for M1.
3. Use script mirasvit_migrate_j2t_rwp.php It will migrate J2T data into Mirasvit.
4. Use script from the Mirasvit Manual https://mirasvit.com/docs/module-rewards/current/setup/migration to create CSV file.
5. Import CSV in your M2 store with the Mirasvit extension.

A bit convoluted but it seems the only way to do this